# Finding intersection points of circle and grid efficiently

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

What's a good method to find the intersection points of a circle defined by it's center point and radius and an arbitrary grid?

An illustration of the points I am trying to find:
[image]

Possible solutions I have thought of so far:

1. Find all the lines that lie between center +- radius. For each line calculate the intersection points.
2. Make the circle an n sided polygon and use a geometry library to find the intersection points between the polygon and grid lines. This would allow using other shapes other than circles as well.

Comment: I'd definitely go with approach #1. Easy to comprehend, easy to implement, easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems reasonable to iterate through sets of coordinates of lines, finding the intersection of each grid line with the circle. However, to avoid ill-conditioned calculations, one should sometimes use y-line, and sometimes x-line, coordinates as the independent variable.  Specifically, divide the circle into four arcs with division points at °45, 135°, 225°, and 315°.

Suppose the circle center is at  xₒ,yₒ and radius is r.
With δ = (r·√2)/2, the range of x coordinates for the top and bottom arcs is from xₒ-δ to xₒ+δ.  The range of y coordinates for the  right and left arcs is from yₒ-δ to yₒ+δ.

Let y₁, y₂ be top and bottom y coordinates corresponding to x.   For the top and bottom arcs use the formula d=√(r²-(x-xₒ)²); y₁=yₒ+d; y₂=yₒ-d.

Let x₁, x₂ be right and left x coordinates corresponding to y.  For the  right and left arcs, use the formula  d=√(r²-(y-yₒ)²); x₁=xₒ+d; x₂=xₒ-d.

As noted in a comment, the equations derive from the circle equation.  In this case, that's (x-xₒ)² + (y-yₒ)² = r², from which we get either (x-xₒ)² = r² - (y-yₒ)² so that  x-xₒ = ±√(r² - (y-yₒ)²), etc., or (y-yₒ)² = r² - (x-xₒ)² so that  y-yₒ = ±√(r² - (x-xₒ)²), etc.

Comment: You probably thought this without writing it down, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit: you don't have to do the full simultaneous equations palaver here, because the lines are always horizontal or vertical.  Just rearrange the circle equation (x^2 + y^2 = r^2) to get x = (or y =) on one side, and plug in the integer values for the other variable.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I've added a paragraph re that