# Finding intersection points of grid lines and objects from an image

Tags: image, image-processing

I am trying to find the intersection points of grid lines and my objects from an image and want to draw little circles on them. If this is possible how can I do it? May I get some help on this, please?

My Image:

[image]

I tried to lookup up this link

[Finding intersection points of circle and grid efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691192/finding-intersection-points-of-circle-and-grid-efficiently)

but did not understand anything